# join all text from nodes xpath

Tags: xpath, rapidminer

Hello I have some html file:

```
<div class="text">
   <p></p>
   <p>text in p2</p>
   <p></p>
   <p>text in p4</p>
</div>
```

and other are like:

```
<div class="text">    
   <p>text in p1</p>
   <p></p>
   <p>text in p3</p>
   <p></p>
</div>
```

My query is: (in rapidminer)

```
//h:div[contains(@class,'inside')]/h:div[contains(@class,'text')]/h:p/node()/text()
```

but return only first `<p>`.

My question is how can join all text in `<p>` in the same string?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will limit my expressions to the HTML snippets you provided, so I cut off the first few axis steps.

First, this query should not return any result, as the paragraph nodes do not have any subnodes (but text nodes).

```
//h:div[contains(@class,'text')]/h:p/node()/text()
```

To access all text nodes, you should use something like

```
//h:div[contains(@class,'text')]/h:p/text()
```

**Joining a string** heavily depends on the XPath version you're able to use. If rapidminer provides **XPath 2.0** (it probably does not), you're lucky and can use `string-join(...)`, which joins all string together to a single one:

```
string-join(//h:div[contains(@class,'text')]/h:p/text())
```

If you're stuck with **XPath 1.0**, you cannot do this but for a fixed number of strings, enumerating all of them. I added the newlines for readability reasons, remove them if you want to:

```
concat(
  //h:div[contains(@class,'text')]/h:p[1]/text(),
  //h:div[contains(@class,'text')]/h:p[2]/text(),
  //h:div[contains(@class,'text')]/h:p[3]/text(),
  //h:div[contains(@class,'text')]/h:p[4]/text()
)
```